# How do you find common sublists between two lists?

Tags: python, list, set, sublist

How do you find or keep only the sublists of a list if it the sublist is also present within another list?

```
lsta = [['a','b','c'],['c','d','e'],['e','f','g']]
lstb = [['a','b','c'],['d','d','e'],['e','f','g']]
```

I'd like to do something like set(lsta) & set(lstb)

```
Desired_List = [['a','b','c'],['e','f','g']]
```

The reason I'd like to do something like set is for it's speed as I'm doing this on a very large list where efficiency is quite important.

Also, slightly unrelated, what if I wanted to subtract lstb from lsta to get

```
Desired_List2 = [['d','d','e']]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better change the list of lists to list of tuples, then you can easily use the set operations:

```
>>> tupa = map(tuple, lsta)
>>> tupb = map(tuple, lstb)
>>> set(tupa).intersection(tupb)
set([('a', 'b', 'c'), ('e', 'f', 'g')])
>>> set(tupa).difference(tupb)
set([('c', 'd', 'e')])
```

Comment: Another convenience to using sets is the overloading of `&` and `-`: `tupa - tupb` and `tupa & tupb`

Comment: will this work if the order of elemets in tuples is arbitrary, i.e. `('a','b','c')` in one list and  `('b','a','c')` in another?

Answer (score 2):

If your sub-lists need to remain lists, use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Intersection:

```
>>> [i for i in lsta if i in lstb]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]
```

Subtraction:

```
>>> [i for i in lsta if i not in lstb]
[['c', 'd', 'e']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written [a C module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BoolMerge) a while ago for this:

```
>>> lsta = [['a','b','c'],['c','d','e'],['e','f','g']]
>>> lstb = [['a','b','c'],['d','d','e'],['e','f','g']]
>>> list(boolmerge.andmerge(lsta, lstb))
>>> import boolmerge
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]
```

This is O(n) time, and require the lists to be sorted.