# How to find sublist which present one list not another list in python?

Tags: python, list, sublist

I need to compare two lists which are basically list-of-list find out the sublists which are present in one list but not other. Also the arrangement of the sublists does not consider i.e. ['a','b'] = ['b,'a']. The two lists are

```
List_1 = [['T_1','T_2'],['T_2','T_3'],['T_1','T_3']]
List_2 = [['T_1','T_2'],['T_3','T_1']]
```

The output list should be

```
out_list = [['T_2','T_3']]
```

Comment: The answer is already answered.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448310/how-do-you-find-common-sublists-between-two-lists

Comment: your sublists are unique, like no duplicates in your list?

Answer (score 4):

For two element sublists, this should suffice:

```
[x for x in List_1 if x not in List_2 and x[::-1] not in List_2]
```

**Code**:

```
List_1 = [['T_1','T_2'],['T_2','T_3'],['T_1','T_3']]
List_2 = [['T_1','T_2'],['T_3','T_1']]

print([x for x in List_1 if x not in List_2 and x[::-1] not in List_2])
```

Comment: That only reliably works for sublists of 2 items, though

Comment: @roganjosh, Yes. Already added to my answer. :)

Comment: So I see :) I think we can do better, with set intersection but I'll need to flesh it out a bit in my head. This is going to have to scan the lists twice

Comment: is this a 2n^2 solution (time complexity)?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little messy functional solution that uses `set`s and `tuple`s in the process (`set`s are used because what you're trying to calculate is the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference), and `tuple`s are used because unlike `list`s, they're hashable, and can be used as `set` elements):

```
List_1 = [['T_1','T_2'],['T_2','T_3'],['T_1','T_3']]
List_2 = [['T_1','T_2'],['T_3','T_1']]

f = lambda l : tuple(sorted(l))

out_list = list(map(list, set(map(f, List_1)).symmetric_difference(map(f, List_2))))

print(out_list)
```

Output:

```
[['T_2', 'T_3']]
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd say [frozensets](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/types-set.html) are more appropiate for such task:

```
fs2 = set(map(frozenset,List_2))
out = set(map(frozenset,List_1)).symmetric_difference(fs2)

print(out)                                 
# {frozenset({'T_2', 'T_3'})}
```

---

The advantage of using `frozensets` here is that they can be hashed, hence you can simply map both lists and take the `set.symmetric_difference`.

---

If you want a nested list from the output, you can simply do:

```
list(map(list, out))
```

Note that some sublists might appear in a different order, though given the task should not be a problem

Comment: Hmm  yeah i think ur right @MrGeek

Comment: The issue now is that you don't get a list output, so one way or another, it's gonna look like MrGeek's answer if you follow it through to its entirety

Comment: Yes, my whole point here is that using `sets` or `frozensets` might simply be more appropiate @roganjosh. So not sure what OP wants to do from here, but depending on the task this might be more useful

Comment: Note that if order is interchangeable as it seems, why not use sets @roganjosh but yeah, if the output has to be a nested lists totally agree

Comment: Wait, I'm not criticising the use of sets at all. I already posted on Austin's answer before this about using sets. My comment is merely that the approach you have posted may appear more elegant than MrGeek's, but it does not give the `list` output. I don't like the look of his answer, but it does actually get the job done and I think it's necessarily ugly because of the problem itself, not bad coding

Comment: Yes yes I know you aren't, just exposing my point of view, agreed :) @roganjosh

Answer (score 2):

You can convert lists to [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) for equality comparison and use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to add into list only items which doesn't exists in second list:

```
List_1 = [['T_1', 'T_2'], ['T_2', 'T_3'], ['T_1', 'T_3']]
List_2 = [['T_1', 'T_2'], ['T_3', 'T_1']]
out_list = [l1 for l1 in List_1 if not any(set(l1) == set(l2) for l2 in List_2)]
```

---

For better understanding resources consumption and efficiency of each answer I've done some [tests](https://repl.it/repls/FrizzyLovelyRom). Hope it'll help to choose best.

Results on data from question:

- [Olvin Roght's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57737553/10824407) - **12.963876624000001**;
- [yatu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57737398/10824407) - **8.218290244000002**;
- [rusu_ro1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57737571/10824407) - **8.857162503000001**;
- [MrGeek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57737390/10824407) - **11.631234766000002**;
- [Austin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57737375/10824407) - **3.452045860999995**;
- [GZ0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57738788/10824407) - **7.037438627**.

Results on [bigger data](https://repl.it/repls/IrresponsibleLazyBase):

- [Olvin Roght's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57737553/10824407) - **83.452110953**;
- [yatu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57737398/10824407) - **0.1939603360000035**;
- [rusu_ro1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57737571/10824407) - **0.24479892000000802**;
- [MrGeek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57737390/10824407) - **0.32636319700000627**;
- [Austin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57737375/10824407) - **5.052051797000004**;
- [GZ0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57738788/10824407) - **0.20400504799999908**.

Comment: what about testing with 1k-10k-1000k, I'm sure that the top will not be the same, with 3 elements the tests are not so relevant

Comment: @rusu_ro1, of course. I've added tests with bigger data.

Comment: The timings are interesting but it's not a level playing field. You can see my comments under yatu's answer; it doesn't give back a list.

Comment: Also, Austin's answer flat-out is not extensible. I suspect you have learned something from the timing of your own answer, though :)

Comment: @roganjosh, I've updated functions to give back same results. And about my answer - It's not a surprise for me. Actually, it's one of reasons why I've added tests, cause my solution looks most compact but definitely not most efficient ;)

Comment: @roganjosh, also I have not updated my answer cause somehow it will be similar with other answers.

Comment: Well that is somewhat admirable. There's always a debate in science about how people not publishing things that don't work is harmful. You did publish.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I've provided a more compact variant of the `frozenset` solution.

Comment: @GZ0, that's great, but in fact there's not so much difference between yours and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57737398/10824407) answer. So I expect result of tests to be really close. Anyway, you show another way to convert list to set using unpacking which can be useful.

Comment: @OlvinRoght The last statement of mine can make some difference when the `List_2` is large enough because it avoids converting `map(frozenset,List_2)` into a set. Meanwhile, unpacking iterables into a list is slightly faster than an explicit `list()` call. However, the difference is very small and only becomes significant when the output list size is very small.

Comment: @GZ0, I've added result of tests of your solution and (as expected) they're very close to solution I've pointed you before.

Answer (score 1):

if you do not have duplicates in your lists you can use:

```
 set(frozenset(e) for e in List_1).symmetric_difference({frozenset(e) for e in List_2})
```

output:

```
{frozenset({'T_2', 'T_3'}), frozenset({1, 2})}
```

if you need a list of lists as output you can use:

```
[list(o) for o in output]
```

ouptut:

```
[['T_2', 'T_3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner variant of the `frozenset` solutions from [@yatu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57737398/10157759) and [@rusu_ro1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57737571/10157759) for those who prefer a more concise syntax:

```
out = [*map(list,{*map(frozenset,List_1)}^{*map(frozenset,List_2)})]
```

If it is not required to convert the output into a nested list, just do

```
out = {*map(frozenset,List_1)}^{*map(frozenset,List_2)}
```

Meanwhile, one advantage of using the `symmetric_difference` function rather than the `^` operator is that the former can take any iterable as its argument. This avoids converting `map(frozenset,List_2)` into a set and therefore gains some performance.

```
out = [*map(list,{*map(frozenset,List_1)}.symmetric_difference(map(frozenset,List_2)))]
```